# Img and text aligned at the bottom

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I'm using bootstrap.

I'd like to align the text at the bottom of the image even if the text is quite long.

[image]

```css
.float{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4">
<div><img class="float" style="display:inline-block;" src="https://img3.stockfresh.com/files/a/anna_leni/m/59/5391508_stock-vector-exam-preparation-app-flat-icon-with-long-shadow.jpg" width="135" height="200"/>
<h4 style="display:inline-block;">Some text some text some text some text</h4></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<div><img class="float" style="display:inline-block;" src="https://img3.stockfresh.com/files/a/anna_leni/m/59/5391508_stock-vector-exam-preparation-app-flat-icon-with-long-shadow.jpg" width="135" height="200"/>
<h4 style="display:inline-block;">Some text some text some text some text</h4></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<div><img class="float" style="display:inline-block;" src="https://img3.stockfresh.com/files/a/anna_leni/m/59/5391508_stock-vector-exam-preparation-app-flat-icon-with-long-shadow.jpg" width="135" height="200"/>
<h4 style="display:inline-block;">Some text some text some text some text</h4></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flex layout. Bootstrap has very good classes to support flex. Below is the updated code

```css
.float{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="d-flex align-items-end"><img class="float" style="display:inline-block;" src="https://img3.stockfresh.com/files/a/anna_leni/m/59/5391508_stock-vector-exam-preparation-app-flat-icon-with-long-shadow.jpg" width="135" height="200"/>
<h4 style="display:inline-block;">Some text some text some text some text</h4></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="d-flex align-items-end"><img class="float" style="display:inline-block;" src="https://img3.stockfresh.com/files/a/anna_leni/m/59/5391508_stock-vector-exam-preparation-app-flat-icon-with-long-shadow.jpg" width="135" height="200"/>
<h4 style="display:inline-block;">Some text some text some text some text Some text some text some text some texSome text some text some text some texSome text some text some text some tex</h4></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="d-flex align-items-end"><img class="float" style="display:inline-block;" src="https://img3.stockfresh.com/files/a/anna_leni/m/59/5391508_stock-vector-exam-preparation-app-flat-icon-with-long-shadow.jpg" width="135" height="200"/>
<h4 style="display:inline-block;">Some text some text some text some text</h4></div>
</div>

</div>
```